# Add user to Active Directory group without using the AD cmdlets

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As stated using the cmdlets in powershell for this is not an option. I've tried to use .NET like this.

```
$Source = @" 
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

namespace some.NameSpace
{
    public static class ADClass
    {
        public static void AddUserToGroup(string userId, string groupName, string domainId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainId))
                {
                    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupName);
                    group.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userId);
                    group.Save();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }
}
"@ 

$Assem =
 ("System.DirectoryServices.dll",
"System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll) 

 Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $Assem

   [some.NameSpace.ADClass]::AddUserToGroup(myUserName, myGroupName, myDomainName)
```

It's however hard to debug and i'm not sure whether it dosen't work, my code is wrong or I just can't contact the AD.

Comment: You could look into https://github.com/lazywinadmin/AdsiPS which is a set of cmdlets that use .NET to perform actions on Active Directory. There is a `Add-ADSIGroupMember` cmdlet which you can use, or get inspiration from https://github.com/lazywinadmin/AdsiPS/blob/master/AdsiPS/Public/Add-ADSIGroupMember.ps1

Comment: Can you post the error code/ traceback?

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to run C# code in PowerShell for things that PowerShell can already do by itself. [See also](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx).